# error when importing google-cloud-bigquery python module

Tags: python, google-bigquery

so i replaced the google-cloud package installation with the google-cloud-bigquery one as google-cloud has been depreacated :

```
Requirement already up-to-date: google-cloud-bigquery in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.5.0)
```

Now the issue is that when I try to import the package I get a syntax error which really I do not understand:

```
    import google-cloud-bigquery as bq
             ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is doing my head in, can someone please help, what is the problem with importing this package?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

`from google.cloud import bigquery`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the syntax error is that the minus sign is an illegal character in a package or module name. Typically packages will use underscores in the actual package names, or have a nested structure, as in this case: `import google.cloud.bigquery as bq`

Answer (score 1):

The `google-cloud-bigquery` syntax has to be implemented during the [**Client Library installation**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library) phase; however, the correct way to [import the **Google Cloud client library**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) is by using the `from google.cloud import bigquery` format. You can use the following Google's official example as a reference:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Instantiates a client
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

# The name for the new dataset
dataset_id = 'my_new_dataset'

# Prepares a reference to the new dataset
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)

# Creates the new dataset
dataset = bigquery_client.create_dataset(dataset)

print('Dataset {} created.'.format(dataset.dataset_id))
```